# Separating image and list so they are in their own line

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make a top and a bottom for the upper part of my website. The topside will have a .svg logo and the bottom is a list. I wasn't able to separate them. How do I give each part their own line?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: block;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

li span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5px;
  /*background: orange;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5px;
  opacity: 0
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px;
  vertical-align: -13px;
}

li:hover span {
  animation: pulse 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(5px)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

hr {
  margin: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span style="position: unset"><a><img align="right" src="C:\Users\David\Desktop\WebDevelopmentTest\images\NotWalla\logo.svg" style="height: 25%; width: 25%" alt="NEWS"></a></span>
</header>
<br>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><span style="background: blue"></span><a href="#shopping">A</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: red"></span><a href="#wanted">B</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: green"></span><a href="#games">C</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: brown;"></span><a href="#TECH">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tourism" style="border-top-color: yellow;">E</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: burlywood;"></span><a href="#health">F</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: cyan;"></span><span></span><a href="#food" ">G</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: magenta; "></span><a href="#fashion ">H</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: gray; "></span><a href="#culture ">I</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: firebrick; "></span><a href="#car ">J</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: olivedrab; "></span><a href="#TV ">K</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: silver; "></span><a href="#business ">L</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: lightblue; "></span><a href="#sport ">M</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: khaki; "></span><a href="#news ">N</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is being floated using inline CSS (`align: right`). As pointed out by hungerstar in comments, [this property is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-align). 
You should remove this and instead you could use `text-align` to place the image on the right.

**example**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: block;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

li span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5px;
  /*background: orange;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5px;
  opacity: 0
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px;
  vertical-align: -13px;
}

li:hover span {
  animation: pulse 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(5px)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

hr {
  margin: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
}

header {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span style="position: unset"><a><img src="C:\Users\David\Desktop\WebDevelopmentTest\images\NotWalla\logo.svg" style="height: 25%; width: 25%" alt="NEWS"></a></span>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><span style="background: blue"></span><a href="#shopping">A</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: red"></span><a href="#wanted">B</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: green"></span><a href="#games">C</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: brown;"></span><a href="#TECH">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tourism" style="border-top-color: yellow;">E</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: burlywood;"></span><a href="#health">F</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: cyan;"></span><span></span><a href="#food" ">G</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: magenta; "></span><a href="#fashion ">H</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: gray; "></span><a href="#culture ">I</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: firebrick; "></span><a href="#car ">J</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: olivedrab; "></span><a href="#TV ">K</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: silver; "></span><a href="#business ">L</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: lightblue; "></span><a href="#sport ">M</a></li>
    <li><span style="background: khaki; "></span><a href="#news ">N</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Would like to add to this answer that `align: right` is how the image was being floated and the `align` attribute [is depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-align) for `img` tags and should no longer be used.

Comment: Took me a few minutes to realise that's where float was coming from... thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

add class .clear to "< a >" tag that contain image

```
.clear {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```